# Changing Values for keys of dictionaries in a csv.DictReader type

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am trying to tweak data that I imported from a csv file into a python dictionary. (I used `csv.DictReader()`.) I think that DictReader created a nested dictionary, with each sub-dictionary being a row on the csv file.

I am trying to loop through each row, changing values that correspond to certain column name keys.

I've tried typing it as `generator_units_dict[row][self.fom_cost_column] = whatever_calculation` but that gives me an error: `'DictReader' object is not subscriptable`

```
def adjust_generator_data(self, generator_units_dict):
       for row in generator_units_dict:
           row[self.fom_cost_column] = str(float(row[self.fom_cost_column])*1000)
           row[self.fom_other_cost_column] = str(float(row[self.fom_other_cost_column])*1000)
           row[self.fuel_cost_column] = str(float(row[self.fuel_cost_column])* float(row[self.heat_rate_column])/1000)
       return generator_units_dict
```

After this, when I run something like

```py
for row in generator_units_dict:
   print(row)
```

I am expecting to get:

```
OrderedDict([('unity', '10'), ('regiony', '1'), ('capmwy', '1250'), ('fuelcosty', '26.851743334570003'), ('vomcosty', '2.17'), ('fomcosty', '30240.0'), ('vothery', '0'), ('fothery', '0.0'), ('heatratey', '7237.666667'), ('so2ratey', '0'), ('noxratey', '0.0730304'), ('availy', '0.8'), ('rmcfy', '1'), ('planttype1y', 'CC'), ('reg512y', 'NY_Z_J'), ('gwhty', '20408.04518'), ('gwhsy', '9543.262571'), ('tbtuty', '145.7268107'), ('unitcodey', '1'), ('winteravy', '0.8'), ('wshldravy', '0.8'), ('summeravy', '0.8'), ('noxmtonty', '1.064248685'), ('fuelsy', 'GA     DZ')])
orderedDict([('unity', '11'), ('regiony', '1'), ('capmwy', '1250'), ('fuelcosty', '26.851743334570003'), ('vomcosty', '2.17'), ('fomcosty', '30240.0'), ('vothery', '0'), ('fothery', '0.0'), ('heatratey', '7237.666667'), ('so2ratey', '0'), ('noxratey', '0.0730304'), ('availy', '0.8'), ('rmcfy', '1'), ('planttype1y', 'CC'), ('reg512y', 'NY_Z_J'), ('gwhty', '20408.04518'), ('gwhsy', '9543.262571'), ('tbtuty', '145.7268107'), ('unitcodey', '1'), ('winteravy', '0.8'), ('wshldravy', '0.8'), ('summeravy', '0.8'), ('noxmtonty', '1.064248685'), ('fuelsy', 'GA     DZ')])
```

But neither errors nor data is returned on the console.

Comment: "I think that DictReader created a nested dictionary, with each sub-dictionary being a row on the csv file." It does not. `DictReader` creaters a `DictReader` object, which is a lazy iterable of `dict` objects which represent the rows in your csv. Which is why when you try to subscript that object, it throws the error: `'DictReader' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: You've said what error you get when you do `generator_units_dict[row][...]`, but what error do you get with the code posted, ie just `row[...]`?

Comment: I've changed the title and tried clarifying the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DictReader is a generator, a function to customize it should be a generator as well.

Example:

**test.csv**

```
a,b,c
1,.01,2
2,.02,3
3,.03,4
```

**test.py**

```
import csv

def customize(generator):
    for row in generator:
        row['a'] = int(row['a'])
        row['b'] = float(row['b']) * 100
        row['c'] = int(row['c'])
        yield row

with open('test.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = customize(csv.DictReader(f))
    for row in r:
        print(row)
```

**Output:**

```
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 1.0), ('c', 2)])
OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 2.0), ('c', 3)])
OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 3.0), ('c', 4)])
```